# iOS button doesn't work after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, storyboard

To explain my problem, this is an example :

I've a viewcontroller which contains :

- View  :
       -> ScrollView :
                      -> ContentView

On this ContentView I have labels etc.. and a button on the bottom with few constraints.

On portrait mode, the button works, there is no problem, I can "click" and start an action.

But when the phone is in landscape mode, the button does nothing. I think it's because the button is "out" of the "View" (when I'm on size class "compact height" for example, the button is not visible on "View"). I can see it when I scroll, but that's all, it's not "active".

How does it work ? What i need to do ?

thx,

Comment: you need to pin you elements inside content view correctly from all the sides.

Comment: your theory about why is probably right.  a quick test to prove it is to set .clipsToBounds=YES; on the content view.  if you're right, your non-functioning button will no longer be visible.  @gronzzz is right about the fix.

Comment: both comments are most probably pointing to right direction. and to solve this there is one more important piece of information missing: are you using autolayout or not?

Comment: Another tip, give all your views different background colours as you may be getting a view over the top of the button.

Comment: Yes I'm using autolayout to use size classes on xCode 6. I don't understand what you mean gronzzz :(

Comment: If I set clipsToBounds = YEs for my containerView, I can scroll, but my button is not visible.

Comment: Indeed, when I set a background color to my container view, I can see the background color only on the "first screen", when I scroll, there is nothing, but I can see my button and others.

Comment: The problem I think is that to use the scrollview, I added a constraint to set equal width & height for the View and the ContainerView. But i don't know how can I solve it, because if I delete that, I've errors...